# Symfony 4.2 update question - Bootstrap.php file unused

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I updated a Symfony 4.1 App to 4.2 few days/weeks ago and I noticed there is now a `bootstrap.php` file inside `config/`. It was added during 4.2 update.

This file seems to do the same thing as my `public/index.php` (checks the environnement, if there is variable in apache or using `.env`, requires the `vendor` autoload.)

The thing is this file is not used.

Should I require it in my `public/index.php` or just don't change anything (and not use it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a default Symfony 4.2 installation, that file is used (`require`d) from `index.php`

So you could remove the redundant logic from your older `public/index.php` file, and require this one.

The same file is required from `bin/console`, so the project is appropriately bootstrapped for console commands as well.

If you are upgradeing a < 4.2 app, and want to use the same index.php file as comes with the newer version, [you can grab it from here](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/public/index.php).

Comment: Seems the index.php from the recipes is working with my < 4.2 app. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Cool. If you need to update your `console` script, you can grab it from [here](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/3.3/bin/console).